# Java - ascii drawing logic

Tags: java, drawing, ascii

I am "drawing" The Space Needle in java using for loops. I have drawn it in 'scale 4', but now I am trying to implement so that user's can type in what scale they want it in ( > 2). My problem arises when I am trying to print the bottom of the 'saucer'. Everything else on the tower is printed neatly but I am struggling to find an algorithm that can print it to scale.

I do have the 'reverse equation' which in my program would be

```
((row*2)-2) + scale
```

Scale is the number the user chooses ( > 2)

This will give me on scale 4 the following:

```
            ||
            ||
            ||
            ||
         __/||\__
      __/:::||:::\__
   __/::::::||::::::\__
__/:::::::::||:::::::::\__
|""""""""""""""""""""""""|
\_/\/\/\/\/\_/
 \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
   \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
     \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
            ||
            ||
            ||
            ||
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         |%%||%%|
         __/||\__
      __/:::||:::\__
   __/::::::||::::::\__
__/:::::::::||:::::::::\__
|""""""""""""""""""""""""|
```

The symbols/pattern I am struggling with are the " \/ ". As you can see I have the following number of " \/ "'s :

Line 1: 4

Line 2: 6

Line 3: 8

Line 4: 10

The following would give me a complete space needle:

Line 1: 10

Line 2: 8

Line 3: 6

Line 4: 5

Perhaps I am missing something very basic, but I am curious to see if there is some kind of logic I can apply to fix it or a simple statement.

Please tell me if you want me to post the whole code

Thanks in advance.

Final result:

```
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                     __/||\__
                  __/:::||:::\__
               __/::::::||::::::\__
            __/:::::::::||:::::::::\__
         __/::::::::::::||::::::::::::\__
      __/:::::::::::::::||:::::::::::::::\__
   __/::::::::::::::::::||::::::::::::::::::\__
__/:::::::::::::::::::::||:::::::::::::::::::::\__
|""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""|
\_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
  \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
    \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
      \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
        \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
         \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
            \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
              \_/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\_/
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                        ||
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     |%%||%%|
                     __/||\__
                  __/:::||:::\__
               __/::::::||::::::\__
            __/:::::::::||:::::::::\__
         __/::::::::::::||::::::::::::\__
      __/:::::::::::::::||:::::::::::::::\__
   __/::::::::::::::::::||::::::::::::::::::\__
__/:::::::::::::::::::::||:::::::::::::::::::::\__
|""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""|
```

Comment: maybe you need to tinker with your formula more? perhaps you mean `(maxRow-Row) *2 -2 +scale`?

Comment: Thanks you helped me figure it out.. I ended up with 
((scale - row)*2) + scale) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karthink T pointed me in the right direction and I changed my formula to

```
((scale - row)*2) + scale
```

And it works!

Comment: Let's see the pretty picture, then  ;-) I would love to see the output of your handiwork in a couple different scales....

Comment: For sure! I will just adjust the bottom of the tower to the scaling and then I will post it

Comment: You should also edit your title.  I don't see how this appies to reversing strings.  I would edit it for you, but I can't decide what to call it... Maybe "_how to draw/scale ascii art_" or something like that??  Also, here's [some competition](http://www.retrojunkie.com/asciiart/building/spacendl.htm).

Comment: Posted in main post :)

Comment: Very nice.  I've cancelled my trip to Seattle!